# Unicode Character Support For... XP and 2003?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I have a few customers complaining that in their Management Console (a web based File Integrity Monitoring application) shows "blank-boxes" in many columns of their display...

Well, it turns out that they are getting these "blank-boxes" because they are trying to load the unicode characters `\u2718` *(an X)* and `\u2713` *(a checkmark)*. Unfortunately, these unicode characters aren't supported on these, may I say, legacy systems? *(hahaha...)*

So, my question is, do you know of a **checkmark** and/or **X** symbol that *not only looks good* but also **loads on Windows XP and Windows 2003**? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a font issue. Can't you load a web font or something?

Comment: If not a big issue they can replace it with an img where you don't need any encoding/web-font.

Comment: Webfonts may work, yet I am trying to avoid using images and icons for the fact that this unicdoe character in question is being returned from and Angular filter on a column in the Angular ngGrid control. Refactoring the ngGrid control to allow the use of icons is simply not worth the effort.